# Platform Builder Project.Dat Issues

Tags: windows, windows-ce, platform-builder

I am trying to customise an image for Windows CE6 using platform builder.

The image itself is fine. However, my customisation is failing.

My project.dat file looks like this:

```
Directory("\Windows\StartUp"):-File("StartUpBat.bat","\Windows\StartUpBat.bat")
Directory("\Hard Disk"):-File("RegFlushKey.exe","\Windows\RegFlushKey.exe")
Directory("\Hard Disk"):-File("TextEd.exe","\Windows\TextEd.exe")

Directory("\Hard Disk"):-File("STARTSFTP.BAT","\Windows\STARTSFTP.BAT")
Directory("\Hard Disk"):-File("STARTUP.BAT","\Windows\STARTUP.BAT")
Directory("\Hard Disk"):-File("STARTVNC.BAT","\Windows\STARTVNC.BAT")

Directory("\SSH"):-File("BANNER.TXT","\Windows\BANNER.TXT")
Directory("\SSH"):-File("error_log","\Windows\error_log")
Directory("\SSH"):-File("RSA1","\Windows\RSA1")
Directory("\SSH"):-File("ssh_host_dsa_key","\Windows\ssh_host_dsa_key")
Directory("\SSH"):-File("SSH_LOG","\Windows\SSH_LOG")
Directory("\SSH"):-File("sshd_config","\Windows\sshd_config")
```

All the files exist within NK.BIN (copied during pre-make image as a custom build action, and confirmed by opening up the NK.BIN file), but for some reason do no appear to be copied to the specified locations, apart from the first entry in the list.

When I altered the second and third entries to:

```
Directory("\Windows\Desktop"):-File("RegFlushKey.exe","\Windows\RegFlushKey.exe")
Directory("\Windows\Desktop"):-File("TextEd.exe","\Windows\TextEd.exe")
```

They worked, however, trying to get them to appear on another partition (Hard Disk) doesn't work. Is it the 'space' in the location name?

The SSH directory doesn't work either for some reason.

In case it is relevant, my "Project.Bib" file is as follows:

```
MODULES
;  Name            Path                                           Memory Type
;  --------------  ---------------------------------------------  -----------


FILES
;  Name            Path                                           Memory Type
;  --------------  ---------------------------------------------  -----------
StartUpBat.bat  $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\StartUpBat.bat    NK     FILE
vncconfig.exe  $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\vncconfig.exe    NK     FILE
winvnc.exe   $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\winvnc.exe     NK     FILE

sshd.exe      $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\sshd.exe               NK     FILE
sftp-server.exe     $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\sftp-server.exe    NK     FILE
AddUser.exe   $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\AddUser.exe     NK    FILE
sockettofile.dll  $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\sockettofile.dll    NK     FILE

TextEd.exe    $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\TextEd.exe     NK     FILE
STARTUP.BAT   $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\STARTUP.BAT     NK     FILE
STARTVNC.BAT   $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\STARTVNC.BAT     NK     FILE
STARTSFTP.BAT   $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\STARTSFTP.BAT    NK     FILE
AddUser.exe   $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\AddUser.exe     NK     FILE
LIBEAY32.dll   $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\LIBEAY32.dll     NK     FILE
OpenBSDCompat.dll  $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\OpenBSDCompat.dll   NK     FILE
sshcompat.dll   $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\sshcompat.dll    NK     FILE
zlibce.dll    $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\zlibce.dll     NK     FILE
BANNER.TXT    $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\BANNER.TXT     NK     FILE
error_log    $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\error_log     NK     FILE
RSA1     $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\RSA1       NK     FILE
ssh_host_dsa_key  $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\ssh_host_dsa_key    NK     FILE
SSH_LOG    $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\SSH_LOG      NK     FILE
sshd_config   $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\sshd_config     NK     FILE
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that re-building a clean CE Image and copying it onto the flash disk isn't enough when dealing in configurations like this.

Once I formatted the flash disk and created it clean with this image the new settings 'took' and everything went to the correct places.

I believe this is down to my set-up using a flash based storage for the registry which isn't automatically over-written when a new NK.BIN file is deployed.